# Variable not defined with bcryptjs in Express

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I try to setup a sign up functionnality in my app using Express and bcrypt but I have a problem. I followed steps to bcrypt my passwords but my variable newUser is not defined.
What's the problem ?

```
    /

/ Register Form POST
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
        const newUser = newUser ({
            name: req.body.name,
            surname: req.body.surname,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                newUser.password = hash;
                newUser.save()
                    .then(user => {
                        req.flash('success msg', 'Vous êtes maintenant enregistré et pouvez vous connecter.');
                        res.redirect('/app');
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: what is `newUser`? is it a function?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `newUser` as a function.
But, if `newUser` is a mongoose schema then the correct approach is :

```
const newUser = new newUser({
 name: req.body.name,
 surname: req.body.surname,
 email: req.body.email,
 password: req.body.password  
});
```

Comment: @qbolgi , I would suggest you to acknowledge if this helps you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looks like a simple typo.
`const newUser = newUser ({`
should be `const newUser = new User({`

new is a keyword which creates objects from classes, in this case, model